# stroke-dashoffset animation with keyframes and css variables

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

Either I'm crazy, or I've found a weirdness with keyframes and svg animation.  I'm simply animating an SVG stroke around a circle that in effect creates an animated percentage dial.

As soon as I throw a CSS variable in the mix, the keyframe animation doesn't animate - it just jumps to the final state.

Here's my PEN demonstrating:
https://codepen.io/tateman66/pen/ePYZmx

```js
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function(){
  
  var percent = document.getElementById('percent').value;
  document.querySelector('.left').style.setProperty('--leftPercent', percent);
});
```

```css
svg {
  height: 200px; width: 200px; --leftPercent: 300;
}

.center { fill: #6d6e71; }
.stroke { 
  stroke: rgba(109,110,113, .75); 
  fill: none; 
  stroke-dasharray: 300;
  stroke-dashoffset: var(--leftPercent);
  animation: left 5s ease-in forwards;
  //transition: stroke-dashoffset 2s;
}

@keyframes left {
  to { stroke-dashoffset: var(--leftPercent); }
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" class="left">
  <circle class="center" cx="50" cy="50" r="25"></circle>
  <circle class="stroke" cx="50" cy="50" r="45" stroke-width="10" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-dasharray="300" stroke-dashoffset="300"></circle>
</svg>

<br><br>
<input type="text" id="percent" value="300" />
<button id="btn">Animate</button>
```

Throw 50 into the text box and click animate.
Then, flip flop the commented out lines to use the animation instead of the transition and rerun it.

Animates with transition but not with keyframes.

Anyone see anything obvious in there?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Because the `to` state is the same as the `from` state so there is no animation. Basically if you don't specify a `from` the initial value of the element will be used and this value is also set with the CSS variable like the `to`. Another point is that the animation will only **run once** so even if you later change some states of it you will not trigger the animation to run again.

You may simply consider transition for this:

```js
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function(){
  
  var percent = document.getElementById('percent').value;
  document.querySelector('.left').style.setProperty('--leftPercent', percent);
});
```

```css
svg {
  height: 200px; width: 200px; --leftPercent: 300;
}

.center { fill: #6d6e71; }
.stroke { 
  stroke: rgba(109,110,113, .75); 
  fill: none; 
  stroke-dasharray: 300;
  stroke-dashoffset: var(--leftPercent);
  animation: left 5s ease-in forwards;
  transition: stroke-dashoffset 2s;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" class="left">
  <circle class="center" cx="50" cy="50" r="25"></circle>
  <circle class="stroke" cx="50" cy="50" r="45" stroke-width="10" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-dasharray="300" stroke-dashoffset="300"></circle>
</svg>

<br><br>
<input type="text" id="percent" value="300" />
<button id="btn">Animate</button>
```